# Tikz Nodes in two columns from a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, nodes

I'd like to do the following. I want to iterate over a 2 dimensional list and place tikz nodes under each other in two columns. Each element contains the following information: name of the node and text of the node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\DTLsetseparator{,}


\DeclareListParser{\MyListParser}{-}



\newcommand\addcase[3]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{list}{database2.csv}
%\DTLsetseparator{,}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix (m) [
matrix of nodes, nodes={align=left, text width=3cm}
]
{
\DTLforeach*{list}{\Nummer=zahl,\Texteins=texteins,\Buchstabe=buchstabe,\Textzwei=textzwei} {
        \node ( \Nummer )  { \Nummer \Texteins };   &   \node ( \Buchstabe ) {\Buchstabe \Textzwei}; \\
    }
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It finally reads simple .csv files. LaTeX however hangs

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\breite{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\hoehe{2.567cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\InnerSep{0.4cm}

\DTLsetseparator{,}


\DeclareListParser{\MyListParser}{-}



\newcommand\addcase[3]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }
}


\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{list}{database2.csv}
%\DTLsetseparator{,}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
      max width/.style args={#1}{
        execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{#1}},
        execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}
    }}
% \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]{
\DTLforeach*{list}{\Nummer=zahl,\Texteins=texteins,\Buchstabe=buchstabe,\Textzwei=textzwei,\Losung=losung} {
        \node [rectangle, max width=5cm,inner sep=0pt, minimum width=5cm, text width=\breite-\InnerSep,
align=justify](\Nummer)  at (0,-\value{DTLrowi}-0.2) {\Nummer \Texteins~} ;     \node[rectangle, anchor=center,minimum width=8cm, align=justify,max width=8cm,text width=8cm-\InnerSep] (\Buchstabe) at (8,-\value{DTLrowi}-0.2){\Buchstabe \quad \Textzwei\hspace{60pt}};
}
%};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

OK, so basically I am iterating (linewise) over the CSV file and use the row number (-\value{DTLrowi}) as y coordinate adding another -0.2 to space between the nodes. I am currently working on a solution with \matrix so that no matter how long the text it will be a fixed straight column. However, on uncommenting the \matrix part I run into issues ( "}" seemt to be missing).

Comment: It would be good if you explain a little your solution.

Comment: @Sigur: OK, so basically I am iterating (linewise) over the CSV file and use the row number (-\value{DTLrowi}) as y coordinate adding another -0.2 to space between the nodes. I am currently working on a solution with \matrix so that no matter how long the text it will be a fixed straight column. However, on uncommenting the \matrix part I run into issues ( "}" seemt to be missing).

Comment: Thanks @Pjotr. However, would be nice if you'd edit your comment into the answer ;-) Thanks